# Why doesn't matplotlib use the .ttf font that I provide?

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a TTF font in matplotlib; the .ttf file is downloaded and lives locally on my machine. I've followed [other instructions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib) for selecting the font using `font_manager`; however, any text that I generate trying to use the font properties still appears in the default matplotlib font.

I know that Python does successfully find the font file, since `prop.get_name()` and similar commands do show the attributes of the font I want - but that's not what appears on my figure. Any suggestions?

As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/Users/smith/fonts/coolfont.ttf')
ax.set_title('Text in a cool font', fontproperties=prop, size=40)

fig.show()
```

Comment: try clearing your font cache in the mpl directory (e.g., ~/.matplotlib)

Comment: I deleted the font cache file in the mpl directory. Running the code again did not change the results. I'll note that it's not just using a specific *.ttf font - even for fonts in my mpl-data/fonts/ directory, setting a different family name in `Font Manager` never changes what appears in the plot window.

Comment: hmmm. Only other thing I can think of is to change your 4th line to: `prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='coolfont')`

Comment: Tried that as well with no luck. Still puzzled.

Comment: I was having the same problem. I eventually realized that I had a line in my matplotlibrc that specified text.usetex = True that I had forgotten to set to False.

Answer (score 6):

its because of the backend that you are using.

When I tried to do something similar with my default backend which is `MacOS` and with the `cairo`  backend it didnt work.

However when I switched to `agg` and `TKagg` and run your example the custom font was there.

Here is your code modified so that it runs on my machine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use( "agg" )
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='Outwrite.ttf')
ax.set_title('Text in a cool font', fontproperties=prop, size=40)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

The resulting image is with a custom font.

Comment: This solved my problem on OSX Yosemite running an iPython notebook in a Python 3 conda environment.

Comment: After switching to agg, using Ubuntu 20.04, I had to remove the font cache and then it worked!