# Why is 'matplotlib' failing to find certain font weights for a specified font?

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib

I'm having trouble getting `matplotlib` to find specific fonts that I know are installed on my system and that show as available according to `matplotlib.font_manager`. When I specify certain weights for use in my figures, the font I specify is not used, nor are other fonts in the chain, and instead a font further down the chain is used.

I can verify this with

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

# The backend doesn't matter
#matplotlib.use('agg')

font = {'family': 'sans-serif',
       'sans-serif': ['Open Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Avenir', 'Arial', 'sans-serif']}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
for font_weight in range(100, 1000, 100):
    matplotlib.rc('font', **{'weight': font_weight})
    print str(font_manager.FontProperties().get_weight()) + ": " + font_manager.FontProperties().get_name()
```

which produces

```
100: Open Sans
200: Open Sans
300: Arial
400: Arial
500: Arial
600: Open Sans
700: Open Sans
800: Open Sans
900: Open Sans
```

which corresponds to what I get in my figures: for 'normal', or for weights between 300 and 500, instead of getting Open Sans, I get Arial.

What's going on here? Why is the `matplotlib` failing to find and use fonts that are present on my system?

---

FWIW, I can examine what the font manager knows about with

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import glob

the_files = font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None)
# Using the_files = font_manager.OSXInstalledFonts() produces the same results
for font_name in ['Open Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Avenir', 'Arial']:
    print('')
    print('** ' + font_name)
    print("Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with '" + font_name + "' in file name:")
    for the_file in the_files:
        if font_name.replace(' ', '').lower() in the_file.replace(' ', '').lower():
            the_props = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=the_file)
            print "\t" + the_props.get_name()

    print('')
    font_in_file_name = font_name.replace(' ', '')
    print("Files found through file system with '" + font_in_file_name + "' in file name:")
    for font_dir in ['/Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/', '/Library/Fonts/', '/System/Library/Fonts/']:
        for file in glob.glob(font_dir + font_in_file_name + '*.*'):
            print("\t" + file)
```

which confirms that the desired fonts are present

```
** Open Sans
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Open Sans' in file name:
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans
    Open Sans

Files found through file system with 'OpenSans' in file name:
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
    /Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf

** Lucida Grande
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Lucida Grande' in file name:

Files found through file system with 'LucidaGrande' in file name:
    /System/Library/Fonts/LucidaGrande.ttc

** Avenir
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Avenir' in file name:

Files found through file system with 'Avenir' in file name:
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir Next Condensed.ttc
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir Next.ttc
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir.ttc

** Arial
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Arial' in file name:
    Arial
    Arial Black
    Arial
    Arial
    Arial Narrow
    Arial Narrow
    Arial Narrow
    Arial Rounded MT Bold
    Arial
    Arial Unicode MS
    Arial Narrow

Files found through file system with 'Arial' in file name:
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/ArialHB.ttc
```

I'm running OSX 10.9.1 and, as noted in the code above, using `OSXInstalledFonts` instead of `findSystemFonts` produces the same result.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you output `the_props._file` as well?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import glob

the_files = font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None)
# Using the_files = font_manager.OSXInstalledFonts() produces the same results
for font_name in ['Open Sans', 'Lucida Grande', 'Avenir', 'Arial']:
    print('')
    print('** ' + font_name)
    print("Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with '" + font_name + "' in file name:")
    for the_file in the_files:
        if font_name.replace(' ', '').lower() in the_file.replace(' ', '').lower():
            the_props = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=the_file)
            print "\t" + the_props.get_name(), 
            print '\t\t', the_props._file

    print('')
    font_in_file_name = font_name.replace(' ', '')
    print("Files found through file system with '" + font_in_file_name + "' in file name:")
    for font_dir in ['/Users/Rax/Library/Fonts/', '/Library/Fonts/', '/System/Library/Fonts/']:
        for file in glob.glob(font_dir + font_in_file_name + '*.*'):
            print("\t" + file)
```

Which for me outputs

```
** Open Sans
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Open Sans' in file name:

Files found through file system with 'OpenSans' in file name:

** Lucida Grande
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Lucida Grande' in file name:

Files found through file system with 'LucidaGrande' in file name:
    /System/Library/Fonts/LucidaGrande.ttc

** Avenir
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Avenir' in file name:

Files found through file system with 'Avenir' in file name:
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir Next Condensed.ttc
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir Next.ttc
    /System/Library/Fonts/Avenir.ttc

** Arial
Names reported by font_manager for fonts in font_manager-found files with 'Arial' in file name:
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
    Arial Black         /Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial Italic.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
    Arial Narrow        /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf
    Arial Narrow        /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
    Arial Narrow        /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial Bold.ttf
    Arial Rounded MT Bold       /Library/Fonts/Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
    Arial       /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf
    Arial Unicode MS        /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
    Arial Narrow        /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf

Files found through file system with 'Arial' in file name:
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow Italic.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Narrow.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Rounded Bold.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf
    /Library/Fonts/ArialHB.ttc
```

I tried this out on my computer and I don't have either Open Sans or Avenir, but Lucida Grande showed up in the "Files found through file system.." loop. However, when I tried a plot, it looks like Arial: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/olgabot/8099973

I think `matplotlib` is looking for fonts in `/Library/Fonts` and not `/System/Library/Fonts` or `/Users/.../Library/Fonts`. So my suggestion is to copy the `.ttf` files over to `/Library/Fonts`, if you can. If not, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574898/how-to-load-ttf-file-in-matplotlib-using-mpl-rcparams) specifies how to load a font from a full path.

It also seems as though there's some issues with `.ttc` font files, so I'd stick to `.ttf` whenever possible.

Comment: We're getting the same behavior. Oddly, I can force `matplotlob` to find and use Open Sans with `matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Open Sans'`.

Comment: And replacing the assignment to `font` with `font = {'family': 'sans-serif', 'sans-serif': ['Open Sans']}` — i.e., listing no other families — works as well. There's something unexpected (perhaps a bit buggy) about the heuristics `matplotlib` is using to locate fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist
```

The output is a list where each entry follows the following structure

```
FontEntry(fname='/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Arial Bold Italic.ttf', name='Arial', style='italic', variant='normal', weight=700, stretch='normal', size='scalable'),
```

In the output list, check how matplotlib requires you to call the font of interest (here: 'Arial'. Next, check if each width is stored in a different font file (e.g., .ttf) with an identical name, but a different width.

Generally, fonts with multiple widths can be stored in two different ways. Each width can either be stored in one .ttf file, or one .ttf file for each width. From my experience, it looks like Matplotlib can not handle which store all widths in one document.