# Use matplotlib.pyplot.rcparams with a custom font which is not installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm trying to use a custom ttf font not installed in the system for text element in the matplotlib figure.

```
with plt.style.context('mplparams.mplstyle'):
    plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi)), '-o')
```

I know I can change the text properties with FontManager but I'm looking for a solution which only involves an external config file.

At the moment I only know that i can change `font.sans-serif` to a font name, not font path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font to be used has to be known to the Fontmanager, otherwise you cannot get it into the plot. In order to specify a font through rcParams this font must be found in a folder matplotlib would look for it. In case you don't want to install anything, you may copy the `.ttf` file to the matplotlib font folder. In my case this is

```
python\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts
```

Then you need to clear the font.chache. Find out its path via `print(matplotlib.get_cachedir())` and delete the fontList files. (Or make a backup first if you like).

Then run your script which has the rcParam specified

```
font.sans-serif : <name of font>
```

or use

```
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "<name of font>"
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574898/how-to-load-ttf-file-in-matplotlib-using-mpl-rcparams).

Comment: So I guess it's not possible to use a path to ttf file directly in rcParams without copying it into either system font or mpl font directory?

Comment: It's definitely not possible to use the path in rcParams. What might still be possible somehow (but I wouldn't know how) would be to specify the fontname in rcParams after getting the font to load into the Fontmanager from a path that is outside the default search path for fonts or to manipulate the search path as to include some custom path.

Comment: I see.. Well since this is the next best thing, I gonna accept this answer. Thanks!