# How to display non-English fonts in matplotlib and networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, networkx

This is a followup question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772950/right-to-left-support-in-python-networkx-and-matplotlib). Since it addresses a more general issue I make it a new question.

I have a network for which the labels of the nodes are in Farsi language (Arabic alphabet). When I try to use `networkx` to display my network it shows blank squares instead of Arabic letters. Below I copy a good example provided in the answers in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772950/right-to-left-support-in-python-networkx-and-matplotlib).

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arabic_reshaper
import networkx as nx

# Arabic text preprocessing 
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'زبان فارسی')
artext = get_display(reshaped_text)

# constructing the sample graph
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a', artext ,weight=0.6)
pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_size=700)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=G.edges(data=True),width=6)

# Drawing Arabic text
# Just Make sure your version of the font 'Times New Roman' has Arabic in it. 
# You can use any Arabic font here.
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=20, font_family='Times New Roman')

# showing the graph
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

which generates the following image:

[image]

I tried to install the needed fonts by following command lines in python, but I get the same thing.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
>>> matplotlib.rcParams.update({font.family' : 'TraditionalArabic'})
```

Here is the ERROR message, to be more specific:

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['TraditionalArabic'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext])
```

I am also investigating ways to install the needed fonts from ubuntu cli, if possible, and put it in my docker file as it gets installed every time I spin my runs.

Best regards, s.

Comment: Is the font `TraditionalArabic` installed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure no. I am not sure how can I install a font from ubuntu cli.

Comment: I think you can download the font here and install on ubuntu: https://fonts2u.com/traditional-arabic.font

Comment: There's an arabic font at https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/blob/master/unhinted/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf , download it and place it in your .fonts directory in ubuntu.

Comment: Salaam, This is almost answered here: [use-matplotlib-pyplot-rcparams-with-a-custom-font-which-is-not-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757755/use-matplotlib-pyplot-rcparams-with-a-custom-font-which-is-not-installed)