# How can I load a unicode font into matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to plot unicode symbols.  I've tried a variety of approaches and always get stuck with bitstream vera sans, which doesn't have the symbols I need.

I have unsuccessfully tried deleting the font cache (`~/.matplotlib/fontList.*cache`), loading the font directly from file (e.g. [How to use a (random) *.otf or *.ttf font in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib)), and some other SO suggestions that I've now lost.

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('agg')
>>> import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
>>> prop = font_manager.FontProperties('/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf')
>>> prop.get_name()
/Users/adam/anaconda/envs/astropy27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1279: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
'Bitstream Vera Sans'
```

How can I load this font, or at least something nearly equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

This could work, it did at least for me:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

path_font = '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmunrm.ttf'
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path_font)
#print prop.get_name()
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 16.
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 12.
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12.
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12.
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line

```
>>> prop = font_manager.FontProperties('/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf')
```

You're setting the first argument, family, but you want to set the file name, fname. So this instead:

```
>>> prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Library/Fonts/Arial Unicode.ttf')
```