# matplotlib tex font rcparams

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, format, latex, tex

All, I am pretty new to **matplotlib**.
How could I change the `font.weight` when using `[text.usetex]`:
In the following code, I am using a greek symbol (lambda) for the xaxis but the weight of the symbol itself seems to be light and is poorly noticeable when a pdf file is produced from the latex file.

I don't understand why setting `font.weight='bold'` doesn't have an effect.

Any idea how could I change the weight of the `{lambda}` symbol. Please, NOTE: I don't mean to change the font size but the font weight.

Thank you in advance!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from list2nparr import list2nparr

plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True 
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'lmodern'
plt.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'bold'

fig = plt.figure()
for j in range(1,5):

  l = str(j)
  ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,j)
  data = list2nparr('pwq'+l+'.txt')
  data2 = list2nparr('ssflux.dat')

  x  = data[:,0]
  y1 = data[:,1]
  y2 = data[:,2]
  y3 = data[:,3]
  y4 = data[:,4]

  mxval = []
  for i in range(len(x)):
     c= data[i,1]+data[i,2]+data[i,3]+data[i,4]
     mxval.append(c)

  fact = 26*max(mxval)
  xc = data2[:,0]
  yc = data2[:,1]
  yer = data2[:,2]

  ax.bar(x,y1, 1.6666, color='#FFA500',lw = 0.5)
  ax.bar(x,y2, 1.6666, color='#00BFFF',bottom = y1,lw=0.5)
  ax.bar(x,y3, 1.6666, color='m',bottom = y2+y1, lw=0.5)
  ax.bar(x,y4, 1.6666, color='g',bottom = y3+y2+y1,lw = 0.5)
  ax.errorbar(xc,yc*fact,yerr=yer*fact,fmt='o',c='k',mec='k',lw = 0.2, ms=2.5)
  plt.ylim(ymin=0)
  ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=16)
  ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci',scilimits=(-3,4),axis='both',labelsize=17)  
#  ax.yaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True

  if j == 1 or j == 2:
    ax.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])

  if j == 1 or j == 3:
    plt.ylabel('N',rotation = 0,labelpad=20)

  if j == 3 or j == 4:
    plt.xlabel(r"$\lambda_{\odot}$, (deg)", fontsize=17,fontweight='bold')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.12)
plt.savefig('figure.eps', fmt = 'eps',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Did the format used in the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899980/how-to-change-the-font-size-on-a-matplotlib-plot not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested answer does not work for me. If I disable the lines:
 plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True 
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'lmodern'

then it works, but what I want is to change Tex fonts. Any ideas.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to specifically use TeX fonts instead of the normal OpenType versions? Latin Modern can be found over on https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm

Comment: The reason I prefer the Tex fonts is because they look nicer and more scientific. Before, I started using matplotlib I was using GNUPLOT and the latex font rendition was way better. So, I thought since matplotlib is so versatile, it would allow to handle the latex fonts much better.

Comment: Right, so that has nothing to do with what I suggested: Latin Modern (the `lmodern` you're calling) is the typeface you're selecting. Whether you load that as "TeX Font" version, or OpenType version, or any other version from the official Latin Modern CTAN repository doesn't matter: they all look the same. So to make life easy on yourself, just use the OpenType versions *unless* those are not available (and as far as I know, all the fonts you might want to pull from the TeX collection have OpenType versions)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. Could you please illustrate how I can "lmodern" with the OpenType fonts? I mean could you show me how the rc.Params in my code should look like?

Comment: look up [how to use a font from file with matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib), and then download and use the .otf file from the CTAN repository.