# Matplotlib: set family of text

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I want to change the font and the size of one of the labels of a pie chart.
The font is called 'Berkelium Type' and according to the fontList.cache file in my .matplotlib directory Matplotlib could load it.

The code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

count  = (1., 2., 3.)
labels = ('Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3')

pie = plt.pie(count, labels=labels)
pie[1][0].set_fontsize(24)
pie[1][0].set_family('Berkelium Type')

plt.axis('equal')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Changing the font size worked so far. However, it did not change the font itself.

I did a test with a simple text

```
test = plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'This is a test.')
```

Neither

```
test.set_family('serif')
```

nor

```
test.set_family('sans-serif')
```

has any effect on the text.

So I'm wondering if I'm doing something conceptionally wrong here.
Is this the right approach to change the font of a text?

**Update:**

I did exactly what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7728665/1391683) is suggesting:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))

prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='/home/sebastian/.local/share/font/kkberktp.ttf')
ax.set_title('This is some random font', fontproperties=prop, size=32)

plt.show()
```

As a result I get this:

[image: Result of the script.]

This is not the font I've chosen.

Could there be anything that is overwriting my font settings?

The font is available [here](http://www.dafont.com/berkelium-type.font).

Comment: what happens if your through a `plt.draw()` in before the call to `plt.show()`?

Comment: No effect. Post edited.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it: text.usetex has to be false:

```
rc('text', usetex=False)
```

Comment: Can you show how to use your solution exactly? In context to your original post.

Answer (score 1):

To change the font globally, you can set this using [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings). Place this line just after the matplotlib import:

```
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Berkelium Type'
```

To just change the font for the pie chart, you can use the `textprops` option to `pie`:

```
pie = plt.pie(count, labels=labels, textprops={'family':'Berkelium Type'})
```

To only change the font to one of the text objects, you can use `update`:

```
pie[1][0].update({'family':'Berkelium Type'})
```

Comment: While this works now for 'serif' and 'sans-serif', it still doesn't work for 'Berkelium Type' or any other font I have.
Furthermore, I do not want to change the font globally, but only for certain labels.

Comment: OK, see my edit with a couple of other options. Both work for me with a font I know I have (e.g. Times New Roman). I don't appear to have Berkelium Type on my system, so I can't check that, but if you have it installed this should work...

Comment: This is weird. I can change other parameters like size and color of the text with the update function. But 'family' has no effect. Neither with 'sans-serif' nor with any font.