# plt.show() can find font, but plt.savefig() cannot

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I need to use a required OTF font while plotting with matplotlib, but cannot figure out how to access it. I saw  [How to use a (random) *.otf or *.ttf font in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib), but neither recommended solution works for me.

Option 1, where I set `prop = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname = '/Users/<username>/Library/Fonts/Univers-Condensed.otf')` spits an error immediately because the OTF font doesn't have the TTF structure expected.

Option 2, where I set the family name to the general name of the font, finds the OTF font:

```
plot_font = {'family' : 'Univers-Condensed',
             'size'   : '11'}

matplotlib.rc('font', **plot_font)

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.title('Show me Universe', size = 32)

plt.show()
```

Groovy! But when I change `plt.show()` to `plt.savefig('test.pdf')` I get this error:

```
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Univers-Condensed'] not found.
Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

Why is `plt.savefig()` unable to find the same fonts that `plt.show()` CAN find? Do you have any recommendations for a different way to approach it? I'd prefer not to convert the fonts to TTF.

Comment: If you write `import matplotlib.font_manager` `from matplotlib import rcParams` and `rcParams['font.family'] = 'Univers-Condensed'` before `plt.savefig()` does that make a difference?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3590  "When you add new fonts to your system, you need to delete your fontList.cache file in order for matplotlib to find them."  "The matplotlib font cache can be found here:
Win7: %userprofile%\.matplotlib\
Ubuntu: ~/.cache/matplotlib"

Comment: I'm working on OSX, so the paths are a bit different. I had cleared `~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache`, but not `~/.matplotlip/tex.cache`. The different behavior seems to come from the continued existence of  `~/.matplotlip/tex.cache`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://github.com/aleaf/Figures/blob/master/Notebooks/Univers.ipynb) explanation this morning, which helps matplotlib find a family of fonts installed in the user profile. It's important to note that both `~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache` AND `~/.matplotlip/tex.cache` need to be cleared. I had only cleared `~/.matplotlib/fontList.py3k.cache` during my initial tries.

I still haven't identified WHY `plt.show()` and `plt.savefig()` behaved differently when only one cache was cleared, but I am now able to save figures with the fonts that I want.