# Font of labels in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts

How to set fonts of labels? Everything in graph is plotted with Latin Modern Roman, but labels not. I tried csfont, but it didn't help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Latin Modern Roman"
csfont = {'fontname':'Latin Modern Roman'}

plt.xlabel(r'$\it{Label2}$', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(r'$\it{Label1}$ (eV)', fontsize=14, **csfont)
```

I tried this for ylabel:

```
plt.ylabel(r'$\it{Excitační energie}$ (eV)', family='Latin Modern Roman', fontsize=14)
```

[image]

and this is result:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a fontdict with the font parameters, specifying the 'family' with the font you want to use:

```
font = {'family': 'Latin Modern Roman',
    'color':  'darkred',
    'weight': 'normal',
    'size': 16,
    }
plt.ylabel('label-text', fontdict=font)
```

or set the family in the label:

```
plt.ylabel('label-text', family='Latin Modern Roman')
```

There's a full [example](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/text_fontdict.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-text-fontdict-py) in the docs using fontdict

Comment: I tried it and the result is in my question - first part of ylabel is not the setted font.

Comment: It works for me with a different font, as I don't have this font installed. Maybe take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib) if you need to point it to the font file.